# Why are Private Beta accounts shown on Flair but not on the Accounts Tab?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, flair, private-beta, combined-flair

Is there a reason why a site that is in Private Beta (for example http://bricks.stackexchange.com) is shown on my Flair, but not in my Accounts list:

**Flair**

Bricks.SE is seen second to left:

[image: Flair, with Bricks.SE showing]

**Accounts**

Bricks.SE is not shown (currently have 880 rep, grown at around ~200/day since 25th):

[image: Accounts List, not showing Bricks.SE]

**Edit to add:**

The current argument that we "don't link to brick walls" doesn't really seem to hold much water:

1. The [Area 51 Proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10919?phase=beta&users=reputation) has links to the profiles of all the committed users.
2. A question [migrated to Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/how-to-best-photograph-lego-blocks) has a link back to Bricks.
   [image]

This makes the account page the odd one out here, and I no longer understand why.

Shouldn't this be consistent?

Answer (score 9):

In the private beta case, anyone not in the private beta couldn't use the link to go to your profile there...so showing it on the Accounts tab doesn't really make sense.  The only way around that limitation is checking if *you're* a member of the private beta, and isn't really reasonable either (for performance, and possibly our sanity, reasons).

*However* when it comes to flair, we show it off, as much reputation as you have everywhere all added up, because showing it causes no harm or navigational confusion.

That's not to say we *can't* filter flair, we certainly can...I don't think there's a strong consensus on this on our side, other than it allows you to have flair if you're *only* in a private beta, which you couldn't do if we filtered private betas out.

Feel free to comment here and throw us reasons for/against a filter on flair.

Comment: That does make sense, and I fully understand not wanting to check if both users are in the same PB on the accounts screen. If the link I wrap around the flair goes to my SE profile accounts page (http://stackexchange.com/users/15574?tab=accounts), it looks a bit odd that the second icon is missing.

Comment: Also, it could possibly be a good way to drive up some additional interest - the login screen states the site's in PB, so the user could bookmark the site for future reference. The Area 51 page lists all the users and has links to their (inaccessible) profiles too: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10919/lego so it's not as if it would be inconsistent.

Comment: @Zhaph - While that *may* be true for some people, our experience has been "don't link to brick walls", which is effectively what we'd be doing for *most* users there.  In those cases, we'd rather not link, since it has a tendency to tease then aggravate users...and in the end they see no content and we get an angry email :)

Comment: You could include it in the table without a link, and with a fat note "(private beta)".

Comment: Fair enough, I can go with that. It does seem odd then that the Area 51 page for this currently *does* link to all those "brick walls" - both the user profiles and their recent activity.

Comment: The whole "don't link to brick walls" argument is getting weaker by the minute: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16741/how-to-best-photograph-lego-blocks This question has managed to be migrated from Bricks to Phototography, and includes the link back to Bricks for all users. Clearly, everywhere else the two week private beta is considered short enough not to be an issue? ;)

Comment: @Zhaph - Your migration example is an *exceptionally* rare case, I really don't believe that correlates to "Clearly, everywhere else".

Comment: Nick, I agree that the migration example is a tiny edge case. What about the profile lists on Area51?

Comment: Whats wrong with listing the account on the Accounts page, but not linking it to anywhere ? and showing a big *PRIVATE BETA* message.

Comment: @AshRj - that doesn't sound very private...

Comment: And on the same scale, showing it on the flair *sounds private* ? ;)

Comment: @AshRj - it's a 16px icon that shows *if* there's enough room to do so, not a large advertisement of a site that may not survive the beta period.  Also as I said in the answer, it makes flair for private-beta-only users possible.