# Show private beta accounts on the reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flair, reputation-graph, private-beta

I noticed that private beta accounts are shown on Flair<sup>TM</sup> but not on the accounts tab or reputation graph of your SE user page.

[This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110529/205264) explains why private beta accounts are shown on Flair<sup>TM</sup> but not on the accounts tab of your SE user page. The reason given for this is a good one:

> *However* when it comes to flair, we show it off, as much reputation as you have everywhere all added up, because showing it causes no harm or navigational confusion.

But I think this argument isn't sound when it comes to the reputation graph: the reputation graph is showing off as much as is Flair<sup>TM</sup>.

> In the private beta case, anyone not in the private beta couldn't use the link to go to your profile there...so showing it on the Accounts tab doesn't really make sense.

Also this isn't a sound argument when it comes to the reputation graph, since that doesn't include links to the accounts.

**So**, how about showing private beta accounts in the reputation graph?

Comment: I wouldn't mind having this, but is this *really needed* ?

Comment: @AshRj no, not _really_, but it would be nice to see your progress on private betas as well, and _why not_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Private betas are, well, private. These sites aren't shown in the Accounts tab, or on the global site list. They are effectively hidden while they're being prepared for public consumption by the initial community of folks who committed to the proposal.

Showing them on the reputation graph would therefore be odd at best. A typical private beta is only a week long, so I don't think making an exception for rep graphs is a good idea.

I realize that Reverse Engineering is now in its second week of private beta. This actually makes it a worse candidate for driving any changes - it will likely be fine in the end (I haven't checked on it in a couple of days, to be honest), but in principle, if a site has to have an extended private beta, that means it's not in the best shape right out of the gate and may never even be opened to the public.

Comment: Now I'm thinking about it, it's strange indeed, as they're private. But then why are they shown on Flair?

Comment: @CamilStaps I'd personally favour removing them from flair as well. I don't see any benefit to showing them there.

Comment: Well, if there's no reason for that, I'll add another feature request for that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173859/205264

Comment: Why not [tag:status-declined] then?