# Don't show private beta accounts on Flair

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-accounts, flair, private-beta

As you can see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110504/205264), private beta accounts are shown on Flair, but not on the accounts tab of your SE account. It's strange that they're shown on Flair, as Anna Lear [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173858/205264).

Why not remove the private beta accounts from Flair?

Or, a less radical idea: show them *after* the other sites, so that they most of the time fall of the Flair.

---

## Note

This is **not** a duplicate of [Why are Private Beta accounts shown on Flair but not on the Accounts Tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110504/205264). That feature request is about *showing* private beta accounts on *the accounts tab* because they're shown in Flair, while this feature request is about *not showing* private beta accounts on *Flair*.

Comment: I'm fully on board with this. There's no reason to show privates betas in the flair. If the site makes it into public beta, fantastic! Show it off then.

Comment: @Anna any updates about it, nearly one year later? You're part of the board after all. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope, nothing to report.

Comment: @AnnaLear fair enough. Hope this request will be implemented at some point.