# Combined flair not updating with badges

Tags: bug, badges, flair, private-beta, combined-flair

I've got **28** bronze badges on Stack Overflow, **10** on Astronomy and **15** on Software Recommendations, making it a total of **53**. Yet, my combined flair doesn't show that. It just shows the combined badges from my SO and Astronomy SE sites. The reputation has no problem. I can see the correct combined rep. Why is it happening? Is it because Software Recommendations is in private beta?

Here are the flairs (Combined and that from Software Recommendations):

[image: profile for Ranveer on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]


[image: profile for Ranveer at Software Recommendations Stack Exchange, Q&A for people seeking specific software recommendations]

The rep on my combined flair is the sum total of my rep from all three sites. But the badges aren't.

Comment: I think private betas don't count

Comment: But my combined rep contains rep from the same private beta.

Comment: @Ranveer so this might be the bug, not the other way around i.e. the rep shouldn't count in private beta sites.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173859/152859

Comment: yup, surely a bug.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110504/241252) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173859/241252) clearly show it's a bug.