# Does network profile show private beta sites?

Tags: support, network-profile, private-beta

My private beta site isn't displaying on my accounts page or on my network profile page?

Is this the expected behaviour (this is my first private beta) or do I just need to wait?

Comment: This has been changed at some point and private beta sites do show in the Accounts tab. (though [not part of the graph](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245726/why-dont-new-sites-appear-on-the-reputation-tab-of-my-network-profile))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is quite normal.  I am a member of a private beta (my 2nd) and it does not appear on your profile until it becomes public.  The answers on the question ["Why are Private Beta accounts shown on Flair but not on the Accounts Tab?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110504/why-are-private-beta-accounts-shown-on-flair-but-not-on-the-accounts-tab) provide the reasons why.