# Why don't new sites appear on the reputation tab of my network profile?

Tags: support, reputation, network-profile, reputation-graph, private-beta

I am a participant on [Lifehacks.SE](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com), which [is in private beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64409/lifehacks). As of writing, I have ~1800 rep on Lifehacks.SE. However, on [the reputation tab of my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/1279912/mooseman?tab=reputation), Lifehacks.SE is not seen in the graph.

On [English Language Learners SE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/), which [is in public beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners), I have a mere ~350 rep, but *that* is shown in the reputation graph.

Since Q&A from private beta sites show on my network profile, why doesn't reputation?

Comment: Because private beta sites are not shown in the graph. There's already a pending [feature request asking to show them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173845/show-private-beta-accounts-on-the-reputation-graph).

Comment: But Lifehacks *is* showing on the accounts tab! (Even when logged out)